# Telerik asp.net mvc datepicker "Invalid argument" in Internet Explorer (IE) 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, firefox, datepicker, telerik

I am using Telerik asp.net mvc extensions. I have an issue that happens only in IE. I have IE 8. I don't have this issue in Firefox (3.6.3) or Chrome (4.1.249.1059)

The problem happens when I want to pick a particular date by first clicking on the year on top and then the month. At that time, I get Invalid Argument error in jquery-1.4.2.min.js

I am using VS2008 SP1 with ASP.NET MVC 2 RC2.

I have tried this in a new asp.net mvc solution after "manually" modifiying it to become MVC 2 compliant and then doing all that telerik says on this page
[link text](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/getting-started-using-telerik-extensions-for-asp.net-mvc-in-your-project.html)
And finally using Datepicker in the Home/Index.aspx

```
    <%= Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
    .Name("DatePicker")
```

%>

***Has anybody else run into this issue?***

Comment: Just a thought - do you have this same problem if you name the object something different than "DatePicker"?

Comment: &Jaxidian, Oh, the above is just sample code that I copied from Telerik's manual http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-datepicker-introduction.html.

My code goes like this <%= Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
                                                                .Name("StartDatePicker").Value(DateTime.Today) 
                                    %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is a bug related with missing line-height CSS style, which is already fixed. More information about the problem in this forum thread:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/error-on-page-when-selecting-month.aspx

Comment: Yes got the SP1 ( had to get the commercial license but I think it is worth it). Thanks for putting such a good product together.